# p99 Latency is High during ElasticSearch Queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a three-node Elasticsearch setup, consisting of one dedicated master node and two data nodes that are also eligible to be master nodes. The index contains 2.2 million documents with 2 primary shards and 1 replica. Each data node holds half of the data (50% in primary shard and 50% in replica).

The issue I'm facing is that the P99 latency for my queries is consistently around 500ms, which seems high given the relatively small data size (6GB). The queries are simple bool must queries with some filters and sorting on a long-type field.

**Additional notes:**
Writes occur throughout the day in batches of 1k documents, with approximately 100k entries written per hour. The writes are updates to existing documents, and the total document count remains constant at 2.2 million.
I am not using index rollover or time-based indices, so all data is present in the same index.
Now, I have a few questions to optimize the performance of my Elasticsearch cluster:

Querying Data Nodes Directly: Since one data node has all the data (50% in primary shard and 50% in replica), will querying that data node directly help improve query performance? Or will the data node still send some load to another data node?

Adding a Coordinator Node: Should I add a fourth dedicated coordinator node and send my queries to it? Will this help improve query performance, and will it distribute the load efficiently among the data nodes? What happens if the coordinator node goes down (should I add multiple coordinator nodes)?

P99 Latency Optimization: Are there any specific configuration settings or strategies I can implement to optimize the P99 latency and reduce the query response time in my current setup?

In an attempt to improve the query performance in my Elasticsearch cluster, I made the following changes:

DNS Pointing for Queries: Instead of directing my queries to the master node, I changed the DNS pointing to send queries directly to the data nodes. Since one of the data nodes holds all the data (50% in primary shard and 50% in replica), I expected this change to potentially reduce the query response time by avoiding additional network hops to the master node.

Refresh Time: I reduced the index refresh interval to 30 seconds to improve query latency.

However, despite making these changes, I did not observe any significant improvement in the P99 latency. The query response time remained around 500ms, which is higher than expected given the relatively small data size (6GB) and the optimized setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set up sharding(routing) key?
And do you use it while querying for data?
https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/glossary/elasticsearch-routing/

For your specific case i would actually recommend you to go with 1 shard and few replicas. Because its not that big amount of data. Basic recommendations are to have 1 shard <= 30-40GB(some say 25GB).

Im not sure that any write optimisations or data/coordinator nodes optimisations are really needed, because your data size is very very small, and if your cluster runs not on **Raspberry Pi** - it should work like a charm. :-)

So try something like this on your index

```
"settings":{
    "index":{
        "refresh_interval": "10s",
        "number_of_replicas": 2,
        "number_of_shards": 1

    }
}
```

---

Also if you can provide any query examples - it would be even better, i can take a look at them)

Comment: Also, take a look at your drives, i would highly recommend to use SSD, and sometimes cloud services provide something like [NO_SQL] optimised instances or somthing like that. From my experience - it can give huge performance boost

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the answer. We are using SSD and monitored disk stats and found nothing suspicious there. We are still going with 2 primary shards but we found that we were writing too frequently. So we changed the batch size to 2k and updated refresh interval to 30s and that brought down our p99 latency to 70ms from 500ms.